# ¿Cómo agregar salto de línea o retorno de carro en data studio?

Tags: google-data-studio

Tengo un campo calculado para encontrar franquiciados activos y cuando se cumple una condición necesito agregar dos Campos a la variable. Lo he trabajado con un `

> concat(campo1,”\n”,campo2)`

pero ignora el salto de línea y coloca ambos nombres o campos en una misma línea.

Les dejo el detalle del `case`

```
    CASE 
    WHEN franquiciado2=1 and franquiciado3=0 THEN listing member
    WHEN franquiciado2=0 and franquiciado3=1 THEN selling member
    WHEN franquiciado2=1 and franquiciado3=1 and listing=selling=1 THEN listing member 
    Else Concat(listing member, “\n”,selling member) 
    End
```

En imagen el problema se resalta en **ROJO**
[image: salida del concat CON SALTO DE LÍNEA en ROJO]

Comment: Destacó que el ‘else’ supone la condición faltante ‘’’       WHEN franquiciado2=1 and franquiciado3=1 and listing=selling=0 THEN concat( listing member,”/n”,selling member)’’’

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del apartado Estilo de la tabla simplemente selecciona "Ajustar el Texto"

[image: Captura indicando la opción Ajustar el texto]

Answer (score 0):

pero el problema no es el ajuste o que no vea el texto completo. el problema es que debe haber solo un nombre por celda. Por eso el salto de linea.

ahora me doy cuenta que `CONCAT` no servirá. necesito dos salidas para una unica condicion. Esto fue lo que obtuve con el ajuste en el estilo: observese que salta la línea pero en la misma celda por decirlo asi, por lo que el calculo para el segundo `franquiciado activo` no se generan. (observen la linea 3)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La sección de respuestas no es una sección de discusión, es para que la gente te de respuestas, si una respuesta no te vale, puedes meterle un comentario explicando el problema de por qué no te vale, e incluso puedes editar tu pregunta para ampliar la información, de forma adicional puedes incluso abrir un chat para debatir, pero la sección de respuestas no es para discutir sobre las respuestas que se dan

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer poniendo doble \n entre comillas simples.

Ej:

```
concat("texto1",'\n\n',"texto2")
```